# Ownership of etc folder is changed how to restore it using commandline?

Tags: permissions, login, etc, rescue

I have a computer with Ubuntu 13.10 installed. The user (say `Walesa`) has changed the ownership of `etc` folder and all its subfolders from `root` to `Welesa` using a privileged file manager. As `sudo` was disabled, he rebooted hoping it will be re-enabled again. But security does not allow log-in after entering username and password saying "owner of etc/profile is not root".

But a commandline login with `I have no name!@Walesa` is possible. Is there a way to restore ownership of `etc` and all its subfolders to `root` using this commandline?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Doing:

```
sudo chown -R root.root /etc
```

on the commandline will set `/etc` and everything underneath to owner `root` and group `root`

However on my system (Ubuntu 12.04) not everything under `/etc` is in group `root`. The following list might help (generated with `sudo find /etc ! -gid 0 -ls | cut -c 29-`):

```
root     dovecot      5348 Apr  8  2012 /etc/dovecot/dovecot-sql.conf.ext
root     dovecot       782 Apr  8  2012 /etc/dovecot/dovecot-dict-sql.conf.ext
root     dovecot       410 Apr  8  2012 /etc/dovecot/dovecot-db.conf.ext
root     shadow       2009 Dec 23 16:10 /etc/shadow
root     lp           4096 Mar 12 19:38 /etc/cups
root     lp            540 Mar 12 19:38 /etc/cups/subscriptions.conf
root     lp            108 Sep  1  2012 /etc/cups/classes.conf
root     lp           4096 Oct  8  2012 /etc/cups/ppd
root     lp           2751 Mar 12 07:38 /etc/cups/printers.conf
root     lp           2751 Mar 11 21:06 /etc/cups/printers.conf.O
root     lp            108 Jun  6  2012 /etc/cups/classes.conf.O
root     lp            540 Mar 12 19:24 /etc/cups/subscriptions.conf.O
root     lp           4096 Mar 28  2012 /etc/cups/ssl
root     sasl        12288 Jun  6  2012 /etc/sasldb2
root     daemon        144 Oct 25  2011 /etc/at.deny
root     dialout        66 Oct 31  2012 /etc/wvdial.conf
root     lightdm         0 Apr 21  2012 /etc/mtab.fuselock
root     shadow        981 Feb 19 23:38 /etc/gshadow
root     dovecot      1306 Jun  6  2012 /etc/ssl/certs/dovecot.pem
root     ssl-cert     4096 Jun  6  2012 /etc/ssl/private
root     dovecot      1704 Jun  6  2012 /etc/ssl/private/dovecot.pem
root     ssl-cert     1704 Apr 21  2012 /etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key
root     fuse          216 Oct 18  2011 /etc/fuse.conf
root     dip          4096 Oct 31  2012 /etc/ppp/peers
root     dip          1093 Mar 28  2012 /etc/ppp/peers/provider
root     dip          4096 Mar 28  2012 /etc/chatscripts
root     dip           656 Mar 28  2012 /etc/chatscripts/provider
```

Comment: but `sudo` is disabled with this error: `etc/sudoers is owned by uid 1000 should be 0`.

Comment: @MinimusHeximus rebooting with `single` on your kernel command line (edit it in grub) might get you a root shell. If not, you can try `init=/bin/bash` on the kernel line instead. Note that later method will leave you with no init scripts run, so you'll have to mount filesystems (etc.) yourself.

Comment: @MinimusHeximus see my answer here http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/119393/33055 to get into single user mode as root, from there you should be able to change the permissions with the command in my answer.

Comment: can you just use `su` ?  get root priviliges then use the command from this answer without sudo?

Answer (score 5):

Since you can modify `/etc/passwd`, you can remove password verification on the root account. Edit `/etc/passwd` and change the line

```
root:x:0:0:root:/root:/bin/sh
```

to

```
root::0:0:root:/root:/bin/sh
```

(i.e. the second colon-separated field must be empty). Now you can run `su` and become root without typing a password. (I think this works on Ubuntu, but if empty passwords are disabled, you can put `aaxSuH/.jTvGs` in the second field instead and use the password `changeme`.)

Repair the permissions by running

```
cd /etc
chown -R root:root /etc
chgrp shadow shadow gshadow
```

and a whole bunch more `chgrp` commands — [Anthon's list](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/119380/ownership-of-etc-folder-is-changed-how-to-restore-it-using-commandline/119382#119382) is a good start.

Once you've done that, check on another terminal that you can use `sudo` normally.

Then change root's password back to being disabled or the one in `/etc/shadow`: edit `/etc/password` and put `x` (or `*`) as the second field.

Finally, send a nasty email to Walesa and tell him not to pull such stunts anymore. It's the equivalent of closing your eyes and throwing a knife in the air hoping that it'll fall down just right to cure your hangnail.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to Anthon's answer above login problem was solved:

I found an old kubuntu 12.04 alternate CD, entered rescue shell, where

```
sudo chown -R root.root /etc
```

could be run. Then we could log in and everything seemed perfect

But sudo did not work with this error:

```
/etc/sudoers is world writable
no valid sudoers sources found, quitting...
unable to initialise policy plug-in
```

I seached the errors and found [this thread](https://askubuntu.com/questions/73864/how-to-modify-a-invalid-etc-sudoers-file-it-throws-out-an-error-and-not-allowi), in which this command:

```
pkexec visudo
```

weirdly solved sudo probelm, the error `/etc/sudoers is world writable` persisting (but not interfering). *wierdly* because I think I did not change anything manually (or if so, I tried to avoid saving).

Then in the same thread, these:

```
chmod u=rwx,g=rx,o=rx /etc/sudoers.d/
chmod u=r,g=r,o= /etc/sudoers.d/*
```

removed sudo's persisting error. Still there may be issues (probably not serious).

Answer (score 1):

I just changed all of my files in /etc to user:user then changed them back to root:root once they're changed, you have to change your user to superuser : `su` then provide your credentials for the superuser account.

once you're the superuser, just run `chown -R root:root /etc`  and you're back