# I can not log into Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: ubuntu, sudo, users

by ignorance and error I renamed the user_name of the directory /home/, called frank_account (home/frank_account) to sixven(`/home/sixven`) (using gksudo nautilus). Restarting Ubuntu, I get 3 users: frank_account, sixven and guest. However,  I can not access to any account with password, only the guest_account and is very limited. entering by  tty (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>), I can log in with the user and pass sixven but I can not do `sudo` as it tells me sixven not in sudoers. And will not let me edit the etc/sudoers file. How I can fix this problem?

Comment: have you tried rebooting in single user mode and change things back from there?

Comment: @Anthon How i do that? I don't know how to do it.

Comment: I am going to write up the answer with some screenshots, please bare with me.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should restart your machine and replace `init` with `bash`:

1. Reboot the computer and hold <kbd>Shift</kbd>, so that the grub menu appears:

   [image]
2. Highlight the second entry and press <kbd>e</kbd>

   [image]
3. Use <kbd>↓</kbd> to go to the line stating with `linux`, then use <kbd>→</kbd> to go to `ro` and change it in `rw`, remove everything after that with `init=/bin/bash`

   [image]
4. Following the instructions at the bottom press <kbd>F10</kbd>

After the message stop scrolling you should have a prompt:

```
root(none):/#
```

which should allow you to roll-back the changes.

Afterwards reboot, by entering

```
sync
sync
exit
```

and press reset

The changes to the grub menu are *not* saved.

Comment: And when i press enter. What Should i do ?

Comment: When did you press Enter? Did you start before I made the changes?

Comment: This doesn't really put the user in Single user mode, it replaces Init with bash. Exit at the end causes a kernel panic and a hang, hence the OP question "And when I press enter, What do I do now ?"

Comment: @XTian, ou are right about the single user mode. I was documenting that process for single user mode (adding single at point 3), but changed my mind without updating the start of the answer.

Answer (score 1):

1. Download a live linux system (http://www.knoppix.org/, http://www.ubuntu.com, etc.)
2. Burn ISO
3. Start from CD-Rom
4. Rename the home folder back to "frank_account"